# $a^k + b^k = z$

Tags: linear-algebra

If,
$$a^k + b^k = z$$
then
$$a^{k+1} + b^{k+1} = ?$$

I couldn't separate the variables, can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: It is not uniquely determined.

Comment: @almagest , what do you mean?

Comment: @almagest sure, but the arithmetic geometric mean of a and b multiplied by z works to get a close approximation at least in integer math...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that there is no answer which depend only on $z$ consider two different expressions with the same $z$, such as $$3^2+4^2=25\quad \&\quad 5^2+0^2=25$$

Passing from exponent $2$ to exponent $3$ we see that $$3^3+4^3=91 \quad \text {but}\quad 5^3+0^3=125$$

Comment: sure but $agm(3,4)\cdot 25\approx 88$

Comment: For another classic example: $1^3+12^3 = 9^3+10^3=1729,$ but $1^4+12^4 = 20737\neq 9^4+10^4=16561.$